# Magento 1.9.3.8 removing redundant tables

Tags: magento-1.9, database, upgrade

Over the last few days I have been carefully analysing my database and noticed some tables, which I believe are from previous versions. Searching my 1.9.3.8 code base to analyse the scripts, I cannot see them being removed anywhere. Thus, how can I remove them?

These tables are:

- commentbox_comment
- cms_widget
- catalogindex_price
- catalogindex_minimal_price
- catalogindex_eav
- catalogindex_aggregation_to_tag
- catalogindex_aggregation_tag
- catalogindex_aggregation
- find_feed_import_codes
- googlebase_attributes
- googlebase_items
- googlebase_types
- googlecheckout_api_debug
- googlecheckout_notification
- googleoptimizer_code
- shipping_matrixrate
- xmlconnect_application
- xmlconnect_config_data
- xmlconnect_notification_template
- xmlconnect_queue

I have also noticed catalog_product_index_eav and catalog_eav are emptpy shouldn't these tables be full or is it also an obsolete table?

Comment: I guess `commentbox_comment`, `shipping_matrixrate` and `uni_fileuploader`aren't magento tables (not checked).

Comment: @sv3n commentbox_comment is present in numerous core location :S

Comment: Can't confirm. There is no no table/code in 1.9.3 ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could add a custom module with a [setup script to remove them](https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/), or run a [direct SQL query](https://a2hosting.co.uk/kb/developer-corner/mysql/managing-mysql-databases-and-users-from-the-command-line), however unless these tables are huge they shouldn't impact anything and won't be worth removing in case it causes any issues in the future

Comment: I could indeed. I also want to know why they weren't removed by default

Comment: I guess maybe to prevent issues with dependant 3rd party modules in updates?

Comment: eddhall, but they aren't in fresh installs. Only when upgrading from previous versions.

Comment: In that case they should be safe to delete, obviously worth trying it on a staging site first!

Comment: eddhall I shall do.

Comment: eddhall should table catalogindex_eav also be emtpy?

Comment: What version do you have/what have you upgraded from?  I think recent versions use `catalog_product_index_eav*`, but if the table is empty it won't really effect magento by existing

Comment: I have just updated from 1.9.3.8 to 1.9.3.9

Comment: Can't see this table used anywhere in the codebase, should be safe to delete

Comment: The catalogindex_eav table?